# Why is fixed navigation box-shadow not displaying properly in Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Everything seems to be working in Chrome, Opera, and Safari as far as I can see.

But the box-shadow below the header part is wrong in IE and Firefox, as you may see.

Also, try clicking the navigation links in Firefox. The website scrolls horizontally as well as vertically, and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your header CSS:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px #000;
}
```

You need to add `-moz-box-shadow` properties for box shadow to work in older versions of FF (Pre-FF13).

Don't forget to specify height: 114px; in the header.

Comment: Nope, -moz- hasn't been required for box-shadow since FF v3.6 (http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow). The issue was that I needed to specify height: 114px; XD